# Feature importance with LightGBM

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, lightgbm

I have trained a model using several algorithms, including Random Forest from skicit-learn and LightGBM. and these model performs similarly in term of accuracy and other stats.

The issue is the inconsistent behavior between these two algorithms in terms of feature importance. I used default parameters and I know that they are using different method for calculating the feature importance but I suppose the highly correlated features should always have the most influence to the model's prediction. Random Forest makes more sense to me because the highly correlated features appear at top while it is not the case for LightGBM.

Is there a way to explain for this behavior and does this result with LightGBM is trustworthy to be presented?

**Random Forest feature importance**

[image]

**LightGBM feature importance**

[image]

**Correlation with target**

[image]

Comment: Different algos may have different opinions of what is important and unimportant (bagging and boosting in your case). On top, you're mixing linear with nonlinear algos (trees vs linear correlation).

Comment: @Sergey, thanks for your comment. I know they do have different opinion and totally agree that the linear correlation might not give you the full picture of the feature importance in tree-based algorithms. But they would still have a saying I suppose. For this case, it is quite a big surprise to me about the small contribution of the top 4 features. Their correlations are just outstanding compared to the remaining ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had a similar issue. The default feature importance for LGBM is based on 'split', and when I changed this to 'gain', the plots gave similar results.

Answer (score 2):

Well, GBM is often shown to perform better especially when you comparing with random forest. Especially when comparing it with LightGBM. A properly-tuned LightGBM will most likely win in terms of performance and speed compared with random forest.

GBM advantages :

```
More developed. A lot of new features are developed for modern GBM model (xgboost, lightgbm, catboost) which affect its performance, speed, and scalability.
```

GBM disadvantages :

```
Number of parameters to tune
Tendency to overfit easily
```

If you aren't completely sure the hyperparameters are tuned correctly for the LightGBM, stick with the Random Forest; this will be easier to use and maintain.

Comment: Hi ASH, thanks for your answer but it does not really answer my question I would say. It is not that I don't understand how to tune LightGBM. I actually know how to do that and do it quite often. It is just the feature importance in this case surprising me and would want to see if anyone have experienced the same thing. It might be because LightGBM manage to find some non-linear high correlations between some features that end up dominating the top 4 features (linear corr). And btw, Random Forest and LightGBM performs similarly in this problem.

Comment: And when I were talking about using default values, I refer to tree-split method. I did tune other hyper-parameters.